Trying to use VBA in Access to force string to be a specific Length
I am very new to VBA. So I'm not sure where to even start with solving this.
I have a phone number entry and to avoid future errors I would like to force the data entered be blank/null or to have a length of either 7 or 10 and the user cannot move off the field if not the correct length.
I tried using IF statements to confirm length and have been able to get a message box to pop up when conditions aren't met but I don't know how to keep focus there until the correct length is entered.
Private Sub InspWkPhone_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Refresh
    If Len(Me.InspWkPhone) <> 7 Then
        If Len(Me.InspWkPhone) <> 10 Then
            MsgBox (" Check Phone # MISSING digits! ")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Ultimately there are several types of numerical data being entered before and after the phone number. I am trying to avoid a zip code or unit price being put in the wrong location.

Don't trap the focus. That is rude. Instead make the control unbound and validate in the save.

btw, Two If clauses can be replaced with If Not (Len(Me.InspWkPhone) = 7 Or Len(Me.InspWkPhone) = 10) Then

As a new programmer I suggest you get in the habit of always including an Else part aligned with every If. It helps you consider all logic branches, provides a place for inline comments for every case, makes an obvious place for future enhancements, allows the use of positive logic (=7 instead of <>7) , and makes your code easier to read and understand. See ISO/IEC TR 2477:2013 D.20.2, second paragraph. It's cheap and it prevents errors.

Don't over-validate. All numbers are 7 or 10 digits long. Until they aren't. Your users will curse you when they try to include spaces in their numbers, or include the international dialling code, or add parentheses around a leading zero, and find they have to stop and work out what you're asking for. Any human using this data to make a call will parse any reasonable format without even noticing.

@BartMcEndree That spec has been withdrawn.

We seem to piling on, so I'll drop in my nitpick: don't call Me.Refresh in the AfterUpdate event handler.

If you use a Select Case approach, you can consolidate the acceptance conditions into one line.  I prefer that to the nested If ... Then blocks.  See what you think.
I discarded Me.Refresh because I don't see a benefit here.
You can use your control's SetFocus method to keep focus there.
Private Sub InspWkPhone_AfterUpdate()
    Select Case Len(Nz(Me.InspWkPhone.Value, vbNullString))
    Case 0, 7, 10
        ' length of value is acceptable so nothing needs to be done
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Check Phone # MISSING digits!"
        Me.InspWkPhone.SetFocus
    End Select
End Sub


That was my attempt to give you what you asked for, but I suggest you consider using the control's BeforeUpdate event instead of AfterUpdate
Private Sub InspWkPhone_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Select Case Len(Nz(Me.InspWkPhone.Value, vbNullString))
    Case 0, 7, 10
        ' length of value is acceptable so nothing needs to be done
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Check Phone # MISSING digits!"
        Cancel = True
    End Select
End Sub


Thank you.  I though the select case would be cleaner but I kept getting errors trying to figure it out.  If BeforeUpdate occurs before AfterUpdate and Exit ,which is triggered by moving off the focus, what is the trigger for the BeforeUpdate?

BeforeUpdate happens when a pending change is about to be saved to the control's Value.  That could happen when you move focus to another control, use Shift+Enter to save the change without switching to another control, close the form, switch to a different form or subform, etc.  Generally AfterUpdate happens immediately after BeforeUpdate ... except when the update is interrupted.
